# ER diagram for public school system

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have these set of requirement:

1. For each school, the system needs to keep track of its unique name, address, classification (Value could be Elementary, Middle, or High), and number of students studying in it.
2. For each School System Employee, we need to keep track of the unique employee number, full name, address, salary, and the school where (s)he works. An individual works only in one school.
3. For each student, we keep track of the student’s name (at times, we need to refer to student’s first name, middle initial, and last name individually), address (at times, we need to refer to the street address, city, state, and zip code individually), the school (s)he attends, and what grade (s)he is in.
4. The system sends letters to High School students frequently, and hence, needs to keep track of each High School student along with the year when (s)he enrolled in the High School.
5. A system-wide list of courses offered is kept. Information about a course consists of its unique number, unique title, and number of credits.
6. For each school, the information about which courses are taught there is kept.
7. For each student, we keep a grade report that provides the grade (Value could be A, B, C, D, or F) for the student for a specific course.
8. The School System owns buses which are identified uniquely by their registration numbers. Some students take them to commute between their home and their school, while others use their personal means to commute. We keep track of which student takes which bus to commute. We also keep track of drivers assigned to buses (a driver is a school system employee who could be assigned to multiple buses, and a bus could have multiple drivers assigned to it – consider this a weekly assignment of buses and drivers).

Here is my attempt at the ER design:

This is my first ER design and i just wanted to know if met all the requirements and if I did it correctly? Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this a real project, or a learning/class project?

Comment: A school assignment.

Comment: @xQbert It is specified that an employee works at only one school (see #2).

Comment: Yep y I deleted my comment.

Comment: Why is a highschooler different than a student? why a separate table?  you also need an associative table between school/courses not all schools may have all courses... I may even have credits on that table too as each school may offer credits at different weights. and you need an associative table between busses/employees along with a Week/year column  Fundamentally any many-to-many relationships should be resolved to 1-to-many.or you will end up duplicating data in tables.

Comment: Highschooler is just a subtype fo student, I created it because it is specified that we want the year of enrollment for high school students. Doesn't the many to many relationship mean that a school can offer many course and a courses can be offered at many schools?

Comment: Yes it does mean that but you have no way of representing the data in those tables w/o repeating data (which you can't do w/ the primary key's defined) So you must you have an associative/junction tables.  think about storing data for Bus1 on week 1 and on week 2 and bus2 on week 1 and2.  on week 1 students ABC ride bus 1 driven by D1 and Students DEF ride bus 2 driven by D2.  On week 2 D2 drives Bus1 and D1 Drives Bus2 and take eachothers routes.  how would you represent this data in your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Met. (though I'd break appart address into # StreetAddress, PO Box, city, state zip etc.(assuming US)  Though if you want extra credit you could subtype addresses into their own table and simply have the employee, student and school addresses all in one table with a foreign key...
2. I'd break down Name, address just as habbit always go to
   the loweest common denominator: Fname, LName, etc... (for scaling
   solutions long term; combining data is easy, breaking it out later
   is hard)
3. Looks good
4. Doesn't grade define Highschool?  a 9th
   grader is in highschool right?  so why a seperate table?
   4.1) now a table which lists what letters were sent to what students might be useful... but they didn't say they needed this so I'd seek clarification on the requirement.
5. if # is unique title doens't need to be part
   of key.
6. Missing (you need a schoolCourses table)
7. Missing (I guess could be handled through your grade table though)  Id call the table studentcourses and keep grade on the table...  then yeah it works.
8. Associative/Junction table between bus/student and bus/employee
   needed

Overall many-to-many need to be resolved as part of modeling. and I agree with Thorsten, I want to see all fields in all tables including the FK's and I've done enough to know the CASE tools allow it.

and while 1-1 relationships look good for 4/5th normal form. they generally are not practical anymore unless the truely represent a separate concept.  So I may have a vehicle table for a vehicle database but I may also have a table for car attributes vs motorcycle attributes vs truck vs boat etc... but vehicle is the primary  in this case there so little reason to separate out high school  I just don't see the long term value of keeping the object separate (but maybe I just lack vision).

You'll learn that in ERD's the cardinality of the relationships between the data is THE MOST IMPORTANT (following datatype/size/scale precsion).  Eliminating M-M relationships is a must. and everything really boils down to 1-M or 1-1 when your done.

Not sure what the line between the school/bus implies....  the buses are owned by the whole system... maybe you need a "System" table tie that to the schools and buses to the system.  that way if you support multiple school systems you know which buses belong to what system and what schools are in what system...

Comment: 2. I just didn't want to add 'year of enrollment' to the student table b/c my teacher will say that it is wasted space, so I thought it will be better to just create a separate table.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by #6. Do you want to keep grade on the 'student' table?

Comment: It would have been done that way 15-20 years ago when space was expensive.  Now we're more about speed of performance and the overhead of the additional join costs performance for the sake of reduced size.  If there was potential growth and a reason to have this (like it could become a 1-M or we could have hundreds of other fields then ok keep it separate) but as it stands... it's not enough to keep it separate in my book.

Comment: Imagine I'm a student registering to go to school... how do I know what courses are available for each school?  where's that data stored?

Comment: I agree with you, but is 'highschool' a correct implementation of subtype? Subtype was a bit confusing to me, so I just want to know if I did it correctly.

Comment: It is; but it's a bad example since each student should have an enrollment date.... http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Supertype-and-subtype-tables-in-SQL-Server provides a much better example using camera, lenses, tripods.  Just dawned on me we're being redundant on addresses you could have a table for all addresses and then simply use a FK to employee, school, student...

Comment: Is schoolCourses just an association table between school and courses?

Comment: And for school system should I just make my own attributes for that since it was not specified?

Comment: Yes.  Contains PK from school and PK from courses so we know what school has what coureses (and it could contain start date/end date so we know when the course was offered.

Comment: For School system you could include district  SystemID, District etc...  you know Schools have districts and each having superintendents etc.  I wouldn't go into too many details (the point of including that table is to show that you're not thinking about supporting just 1 school system/district but all school systems/districts (shows abiltiy to scale your solution)

Comment: That is all the questions I have. Thanks for all your help! I understand this much better now.

Comment: One last question, are any of these entities examples of weak entities?

Comment: If you keep the highschoolers table separate it would likely be an example; as by itself; it's dependent on student existing it's key is the FK of one or more tables.The junction/associative tables are week entities as each one is dependent on the keys of the parent tables.  By definition a week entity uses as it's key, FK's from one or more tables along with a sequence  Header/Detail records are excellent examples of this as well.  Order Header, Order Items Order Items is weak as the PK would be the orderNumber plus a line number.  in a 1-1 relationship the line number would be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I don't like it to omit columns necessary for forein keys, e.g. a school ID in the employee table. But I don't know enough about ER diagrams to say if that would even be allowed.

The diagram looks fine to me. Some points though:

1. School names can change. If there is a number system available (such as NCES School ID for USA) I'd make this the PK instead.
2. Numbers of students must be no column in the school table; the number of students per school is implicitly given by the students related to the school.
3. I don't like 1:1 relations very much. Student <-> High Schooler is okay, but I'd rather have the enrollment date in the students table.
4. StudentID alone can't possible the PK for the grades table. It must be StudentID + Course# instead.
5. The line from student to course is superfluous, because the relation is given by the grades table already (which is a bridge table containing StudentID, Course# and an optional grade).
6. The course table's PK must not be Course# + Title, because that would mean the same course number would be allowed in combination with different titles. The PK should be the course number alone. As to the relation: I don't know if the same course can be taught at different schools. If so, the relations are correct.

Comment: Agree with comments.

Comment: I fixed all the issues you pointed out. I just wanted to ask if it is incorrect to have number of students as a column or is it just unnecessary. I had a similar example in my book and they put number_of_employees as an attribute to the entity 'department'. And there was a relationship between employee and department

Comment: It's not incorrect as it could save time in calculating; but understand it could have the WRONG value and it is redundant as you can calculate the value for each school.  in some systems you could have a function based index or a computed column that calculates this value in a pseudo column instead of storing it in the database.  The fxn based index or computed columns simply look up the value each time but act like a column in the table.  that way the value is never wrong.

Comment: Is that the same as claiming it to be a derived attribute?

Comment: That would be true.  We can derive the student count from the number of distinct students taking a course at the school.